# How to make <button> act like a radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a list of buttons that are in a table, and I essentially want them to act like radio buttons. If `<button>` is clicked, the `.active` class gets removed from whatever button was previously selected, and gets added to whichever one I selected. Only one can be selected.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a common class to every button. Every time user clicks to any of them, remove `active` class from all buttons and add it to the clicked one:

```
$(document).on('click', '.radio-button', function() {
   //Remove active class from all buttons
   $('.radio-button').removeClass('active');
   //Add active class to the clicked button
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: That was a lot simpler than I thought and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var allButtons = $('table button'); // use appropriate selector

allButtons.on('click', function () {
    allButtons.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```